# Error in RShiny ui.r argument missing

Tags: r, shiny

Trying to create a ui.r file for plotting a logistic regression with the following features:

selecting inputs (y-variable: breakdown, x-variables: Temperature, Humidity, Hours) and variable range slider.

I got the following error: `Error in tag("div", list(...)) : argument is missing, with no default`

```
require(shiny)    
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Home Automation Data Model - TV"),      
  sidebarPanel(
    wellPanel(
      selectInput(
        inputId = "x_var",
        label = "X variable",
        choices = c(
          "Temperature (Celcius)" = "Temp",
          "Humidity (Percentage)" = "Hum",
          "Hours" = "Hrs"
        ),
        selected = "Temperature"
      ),

      uiOutput("x_range_slider")
    ),      

    wellPanel(
      selectInput(
        inputId = "y_var",
        label = "Y variable",
        choices = c("Breakdowns (Yes/No)" = "y"),
      ),

      uiOutput("y_range_slider")
    ),        

    wellPanel(
      p(strong("Model predictions")),
      checkboxInput(inputId = "mod_logistic",    label = "Logistic (dot-dash)"),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.mod_loess == true",
        sliderInput(
          inputId = "mod_loess_span",
          label = "Smoothing (alpha)",
          min = 0.15,
          max = 1,
          step = 0.05,
          value = 0.75
        )
      )
    )
  ),

  mainPanel(
    plotOutput(outputId = "main_plot"),        
    conditionalPanel(
      "input.mod_logistic == true",
      p(strong("Logit model")),
      verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "mod_logistic_text")
    ),
  )      
))
```

> Error in tag("div", list(...)):argument is missing, with no default

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Delete the last comma in your ui.R file. It's expecting an argument after the comma.

Comment: Right, and this belongs to the [list of common errors with shiny](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/shiny-discuss/-4c2JYYKeAI/discussion) (which is waiting for some improvements)