# mainPanel argument missing in ui.r file using R's Shiny package

Tags: r, shiny

I am running `Shiny` in R to create a GUI, and I receive the following error: `ERROR: argument "mainPanel" is missing, with no default`

However, as you can see from my code below in the ui.r file, I do have `mainPanel` included at the bottom, which should be getting successfully passed to `sidebarLayout`:

```
require(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
titlePanel("Approach"),
sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
        fileInput('file1', 'Choose file to upload',
                accept = c(
                    'text/csv',
                    'text/comma-separated-values',
                    'text/tab-separated-values',
                    'text/plain',
                    '.csv',
                    '.tsv'
                )
        )

    )
),
    mainPanel(
        plotOutput("plot")
    )



)
)
```

I have also made sure to include a comma before `mainPanel`, as suggested in [Error in RShiny ui.r argument missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22626412/error-in-rshiny-ui-r-argument-missing)

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `mainPanel` needs to be called inside the `sidebarLayout` function. See `?sidebarLayout` :

```
require(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Approach"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput('file1', 'Choose file to upload',
                accept = c(
                  'text/csv',
                  'text/comma-separated-values',
                  'text/tab-separated-values',
                  'text/plain',
                  '.csv',
                  '.tsv'
                )
      )

    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot")
    )
  )
)
)
```