# Shiny app importing a CSV to make histogram

Tags: r, csv, histogram, shiny

I've been breaking my head trying to get my first Shiny App to work, but I'm getting an error that says "ERROR: argument "mainPanel" is missing, with no default"

I have no idea what to do.

The ui.R:

```
library(shiny) 

shinyUI(fluidPage(
titlePanel(title = h4("Katrina Data Shiny Application - a histogram", align = "center")),
sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(

      selectInput("var", 
              "1. Select the variable from the katrina dataset", 
              choices = c("flood depth", "log_medinc"),
              selected = "flood_depth"),

      sliderInput("bins", 
              "2. Select the number of bins for the histogram", 
              min=5, 
              max=50, 
              value=15
              )

      )
  ),

    mainPanel(
  plotOutput("myhist"))

)
)
```

And my Server.R:

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(
  function(input, output) {



katrina = read.csv("katrina.csv")

output$myhist <- renderPlot ({
  data <- switch(input$var,
      "flood depth" = katrina$flood_depth,
      "log_medinc" = katrina$log_medinc)
  color <- switch(input$var,
      "flood depth" = "darkgreen",
      "log_medinc" = "deepskyblue"),
  legend <- switch(input$var,
      "flood depth" = "flood depth",
      "log_medinc" = "log_medinc")

  hist(var = data, color = color, l=input$bins+1, legend.title = legend)


    })

  }

)
```

Comment: @miles2know if you do not want to answer the question, you can simply ignore the question. No need to make snarky comments.

Comment: agreed...sorry.up a bit late. glad you got things working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Googling for the error lead me to [the following SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25225900/mainpanel-argument-missing-in-ui-r-file-using-rs-shiny-package). The problem is that `mainPanel` should be called within `sideBarLayout`. At a casual glance it looks like you do this, but careful inspection of the brackets reveals that you do not in fact. The correct `ui.R` should be:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel(title = h4("Katrina Data Shiny Application - a histogram", align = "center")),
  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(

      selectInput("var", 
                  "1. Select the variable from the katrina dataset", 
                  choices = c("flood depth", "log_medinc"),
                  selected = "flood_depth"),

      sliderInput("bins", 
                  "2. Select the number of bins for the histogram", 
                  min=5, 
                  max=50, 
                  value=15
      )

    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("myhist")
    )
  )
)
)
```

Comment: Thank you so, so much. I didn't realize my parenthesis were off!!