# How can I see value of `input object` during app runtime? Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

For example when the shiny app runs, I can pass `input$num` and the output will be reactive, in this case in the renderPlot:

```
renderPlot({ 
    hist(rnorm(input$num))
)}
```

Is there a way to view the entire `input object` while the app is running?

Comment: Did you have a look at this? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31920286/effectively-debugging-shiny-apps) and this `options(shiny.trace=TRUE)`

Comment: You can probably `str(cat(input))` to see the inputs in the console, or you can render them into a textOutput